# What are some user friendly image processing libraries?

Tags: c++, image, libraries

I'm an embedded systems programmer, and have done extremely limited Windows development. That said I am firm about sticking to C++ since it's more familiar than C#, and trying to figure out a new language is not an option in the time frame available.

The project I'm working on right now is a simple console application for lab use. The I/O and loops are done, the part I'm having trouble with is the image processing. What I need to do is scan through the image pixel by pixel and compare the colors against some threshold values. The image will be a sample on a green screen, and we'll be looking at the differences in colors of the sample. The comparison logic is easy, but after spending several hours on Google and downloading a couple libraries, I'm convinced there is just too much information on image processing.

Is there an image processing library out there that will allow me to load an image into memory, scan through pixel by pixel, load the color bytes with a single function call, and not make my head explode?

Comment: Windows? Windows CE? Linux? Android? iOS? The answer might be different for each of these OSes.

Answer (score 3):

For C++, there's an [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) toolset (it's open-source). The minimalistic (one-file only) library: [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/).

For sophisticated processing try [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com).

If all you really need is to get an access to raw bytes (loaded from some common file format), then [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is also an option.

For C#, [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com) as a starting point.

---

For simple console processing I would opt to CImg (the compile time may be disappointing though).

Comment: ImageMagick and CImg were the two looking most promising. The only bad thing about CImg is the supported file types are limited, and ImageMagick integration is required to add more. I'm having a very hard time finding information on integrating the two.

Comment: Then the next candidate if FreeImage. It's an easy to integrate solution with clean C API.

Comment: FreeImage looks promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but if you're okay with a C-style interface, [ccv](http://libccv.org/) has been making the rounds recently as a modern version of [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).

Comment: +1, but ccv appears to focus on advanced topics. 'Stroke Width Transform' sounds exceptional, for instance...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest GDAL http://www.gdal.org/. It has a function called RasterIO that can fulfill your requirement. Another advantage of this library is that it can handle almost all different kinds of image formats.